# App Inventor: Making one button change more than one variable

Tags: variables, sprite, artificial-intelligence

This is about App Inventor 2, i had a button which could change depending on what image sprite had been activated. However, i deleted this button accidentally and lost all of the blocks assigned to it. I cannot remember how to do it. Could someone please tell me how I create a button that can change the value of more than one variable depending on what image sprite has been activated?

Answer (score 0):

You can set specific counter for specific sprite. Just set the counter when the sprite is touched. Then, when the button is clicked, you need to use if and else function to check for what sprite is touched. Below is an example of code, yet it is not complete:

[image]